# how to access laravel controller function with login to application

Tags: android, laravel, httpwebrequest

I have this Controller in my application with function which i'm trying to access via android app using httpRequest but i'm getting login page of app bcz i can't access this function without login

so how can i make it accessible without login

//Controller code

```
class sobha_tab_empVer_Controller extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
    public function employeeverification(Request $request){
                     $EmpDetails = employees::select()
                                           ->where('employees.EMPID', '=', $request->emp_id)
                                          //->where('vw_assembly_plan_reports.id', '=', $request->zone)
                                           ->get();
//dd($EmpDetails);
                                    //       dd($ProjectDetails);
                  //  return response($EmpDetails);
  return response()->json($EmpDetails);
        }
}
```

//android side

```
  //Some url endpoint that you may have
              String myUrl = "http://......./employeeverification?emp_id=1350";
                    //String to place our result in
                    String result;
                    //Instantiate new instance of our class
                    HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest();
                    //Perform the doInBackground method, passing in our url
                    try {
                        result = getRequest.execute(myUrl).get();
                        Log.e("RESULT", "RESULT: " + result);

                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Try commenting out [$this->middleware('auth');] in the __construct() method.

Comment: its removed still same issue...

Comment: check your routes > web.php check if there is any middleware auth function that is group by sobha_tab_empVer_Controller then try removing/commenting it out.

Comment: Route::get('/sobhatab/employeeverification','sobha_tab_empVer_Controller@employeeverification')->name('sobhatab.employeeverification');  this is in web.php no middleware

Comment: does that require authentication to access the controller?

Comment: yes its redirecting to login page

Comment: you need to access this through API which can be set up using the laravel passport

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
  $this->middleware('auth');
```

in the __construct()

Answer (score 0):

You are using `auth` middleware in your controller. That means no one can access the controller functions without login. You have to remove the following function from the controller if you want to access functions of the controller without login.

```
public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }
```